# Execute a method after all messages are put to kafka in spring cloud integration flow after split

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How can I execute a method after all the messages are put on to Kafka after split.

I have tried using handle() after channel, but that ends up not posting from 2nd message on to Kafka.

```
 IntegrationFlowBuilder flowBuilder = IntegrationFlows
        .from(() -> jdbcTemplate....);
 flowBuilder.split();
 flowBuilder.channel(messageChannel);
```

I would like to execute a method after writing all the split messages to Kafka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you split and only after that send to the Kafka, there is no way to catch all of them, unless `aggregate` afterwards. You can do that with the `publishSubscribeChannel` to send to the Kafka and aggregator the same message. When aggregator releases a group, you are good to perform your method call.

Comment: Thank you, by using publish subscribe, I was able to aggregate and then used handle.